# "vars" argument in plot function in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm looking at the Julia package "DifferentialEquations.jl", a differential equation solver package in Julia. In the [tutorial page](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/tutorials/ode_example.html#Plotting-Solutions-1) , there is an example solving the Lorenz equations and plotting the Lorenz butterfly. To plot the Lorenz butterfly, the command used is

```
plot(sol, vars=(1,2,3))
```

I understand roughly that the "vars" specifies the data used as the 3 axes. However, I never found this "vars" in the documentation of "plot", or of "DifferentialEquations.jl". What is it logically? Seems the function "plot" has many keys but "vars" is not one of them.

Any idea where I could find it?

For example, if I try:

```
t=[0.0:0.1:2*pi;]
points = [sin(t), cos(t)]
plot(points, vars=(1,2))
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is defined in DifferentialEquations.jl - the package has used what we call a "recipe" to overload Plots' `plot` function to take a new keyword if the object passed to `plot` is a `Solution`. You can find the DiffEq-specific plot keywords documented here: https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/basics/plot/

Comment: Just to add to this: var=[(0,1),(1,2)] plots the time vs. the first dimension and the first vs the second dimension.